# Функция умножения с неопределенным количеством аргументов

Tags: javascript, функции, рекурсия, стек

Есть необычная функция умножения:

```js
function multiply(param) {
  this.tmp = this.tmp === undefined ? param : this.tmp * param;
  console.log('>', this.tmp);
  return multiply;
}

console.log(multiply(2)(10)(3)(6)); //2*10*3*6 = 360
```

И есть цепочка, (которая может быть длиной от 2 вызовов до *скольки угодно*)

```
console.log(multiply(2)(10)(3)(6));
```

по выполнении которой вернется `[Function: multiply]`. Но интересно, можно ли каким либо образом вернуть итоговое значение вместо функции?
Возможно есть какой-то вариант отловить, когда Multiply вызывается в последний раз, чтобы подменить return? Или существует какой-то другой подход к решению данной задачки?

*Возможно задача надуманная, и не имеет за собой действительного решения*

Comment: Никакого «последний раз» поймать нельзя. Можно попробовать переопределить методы valueOf и toString

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/task/sum-many-brackets очень похоже

Comment: @AlexeyTen спасибо большое! То что нужно :)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить вторым параметром функции счётчик $counter. Инкременируйте его сравнивайте с ним что вам нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы ходите использовать сколько угодно аргументов для функции, можно их не объявлять, но получать через `arguments`.

### Пример умножения с `n`-ым количеством аргументов:

```js
function multiply() {
  let args = [].slice.call(arguments);
  let sum = args.length ? args.reduce(((a, b) => a * b)) : null;
  return sum;
}


console.log(multiply(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
console.log(multiply(-1, -2, 0.5, 100, 6));
console.log(multiply());
```

Как вы можете видеть, в функции мы не объявили ни одного аргумента, но получили их массив через `arguments`, число переданных аргументов может быть каким угодно.

Я думаю вы именно это решение ищите.

Answer (score 0):

Недавно решал подобную задачу, только нужно было уметь еще передавать название метода объекта `Math` или свой callback

```
function calc(a) {
 const args = [];
 let sum = a;
 args.push(a);

 const func = (b) => {
   if (typeof b === 'function') {
    b.toString = () => b(args);
    return b;
   }

   if (typeof b === 'string') {
     Math[b].toString = () => Math[b](...args);
     return Math[b];
   }

   args.push(b);
   sum += b;

    return func;
 };

 func.toString = () => sum;

 return func;
}
```

Работало так:

```
calc(5)(12)((args) => {
  return args.reduce((sum, a) => {
    return sum + a;
  }, 0);
}); // вернет 17
```

Степень:

```
calc(5)(2)('pow'); // вернет 25
```

Живой пример [на jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uxjnye42/3/)